# "Followed posts" filter drop down has misaligned arrows

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, follow-post

In the [following posts tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=following) of my profile I see these arrows:

> [image: Not right most arrows]

Comment: In `stacks.css`, in the `.s-select > select` selector, replacing the `width: 100%;` property by `width: min-content;` or simply removing it solves the issue. I believe this extra space comes from the space occupied by the `<option>` elements, though I’m not entirely sure how or why this works.

Answer (score 6):

If we take a look at the HTML markup, this is, indeed, just a `<select>` element with some `<option>` elements wrapped into a `<div>` container:

```html
<div class="s-select d-inline-block">
    <select id="post-type-select" class="js-select-post-type">
        <option value="" selected="">All</option>
        <option value="answers">Answers only</option>
        <option value="questions">Questions only</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Now, highlight the container with the `s-select` CSS class using developer tools. You will immediately notice something is wrong: its width is smaller than the one of its direct and only child, the `<select>` element:

[image: highlighted container]

How did this happen? Let's first highlight the `<select>` element itself:

[image: highlighted select]

Now the problem should be clear - the [box](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Introduction_to_the_CSS_box_model) of the container is smaller because of the protruding padding-box of the `<select>` element. Which suggests that we have to look for the [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) property of the container if we want to get to the bottom of this. The stylesheet tells us the following:

```css
body *, body *:before, body *:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}
```

Which means that every element (including those with a `::before` or `::after` pseudo-elements) gets its `box-sizing` set to a special value via the [`inherit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inherit) keyword. Its presence ensures the element the ruleset is applied to will use the `box-sizing` of the parent element.

Skipping past a bunch of `inherit` values, we finally arrive at the parent element that has the property set to a concrete value:

```css
.subheader {
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

`content-box` is a default and [`initial`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial) CSS value for the property, and it *does not include* either padding, border, or margin when determining the element's final size. Since it gets inherited all the way down to our element, we end up with the situation that the container (lacking padding) is smaller than the child (with a large `padding-right` value).

We do not want to cause unnecessary trouble down the inheritance tree, so let's just ensure the `<select>` container gets the correct `box-sizing` value, which would be `border-box` as it has to include the `padding`:

```css
.s-select {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    /* other rules */
}
```

And voila, of course, the issue is now gone:

[image: container with box-sizing set to boder-box]

Determining the best way of overriding the `box-sizing` so as to not cause unintended side-effects is left as an exercise for the <s>company</s> reader.

Comment: You passed the test! You're eligible to join SE as developer. :-D